# jQuery, checking to see if video has height/width

Tags: jquery, dom, video

I have a `<video>` element that is generated by js, and I need to get the height and width of it.

`var v = $('video'); v.height()` returns null, because when it's run, the video hasn't yet been loaded, so no dimensions in the DOM.

How do I check to see if the video has received a dimension, and if it hasn't, wait till it has to get the height and width.

Thanks.

Edit:

I've created a jsbin with my example code:

http://jsbin.com/udazu/2/edit

Thanks.

Edit: whoops, made an error in the sample code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update based on new code** - You can use the [`loadedmetadata` event](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/video.html#mediaevents) for this, [I've updated your jsbin example here with this](http://jsbin.com/udazu/3/edit)

```
$('input').click(function () {
  $('#thumbnail video').clone().bind('loadedmetadata', function() {
    alert($('#viewing-area video').height());
  }).appendTo('#viewing-area');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, however, the video is generated by js after the page is already loaded, due to user interaction, I tried using .load on the video element specifically... but that doesn't quite work either.

Comment: I've added a jsbin with sample code in it, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Mark - Thanks for the example, I updated the answer for this, let me know if it needs another tweak :)