# IE8 : fire the "loadedmetadata" event

Tags: javascript, events, internet-explorer-8, mediaelement.js

I'm trying to fire the "loadedmetadata", an event from which I re-create a video tag (because I need the dimensions of the original loaded video).

I've already seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769868/addeventlistener-not-working-in-ie8) from which I coded this example :

```
if (!$("mySelector").addEventListener) {
    $("#mySelector").addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function(e){
        alert("Fired with addEventListener!");
    }, false);
}
else {
    $("#mySelector").attachEvent("onloadedmetadata", function(e){
        alert("Fired with attachEvent!");
    });
}
```

With IE8, I have a beautiful "Object doesn't support this property or method". What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should not combine jQuery with JavaScript methods. Use the `.bind()` method to add the `loadedmetadata` event, like:

```
$('#myMedia').bind('loadedmetadata', function(e){
  // e is Event Object jQuery handles
  var ht = $(this).height(), wd = $(this).width();
});
```

Since `.addEventListener()` was standardized as of IE9 and Media Events don't exist until IE9 it will never fire with `.attachEvent()`. Neither of those methods is a property of the Object the jQuery function `$()` returns anyways.

If the above solution does not work you should look at this:

[jQuery, checking to see if video has height/width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717986/jquery-checking-to-see-if-video-has-height-width)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly, IE8 doesn't fire the event and .width()/.height() doesn't work neither when my video is loaded.